# Universal Google Analytics Event Tracking Not Working

Tags: events, analytics, tracking

I have read all topics on the subject, and my code is still not tracking any events in the G Analytics. Please Help! Here goes the code:

The Analytics code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1’, 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The code in the button that opens a link in a new window:

```
<a href="http://website.com” onClick="ga('send','event','Tickets','Buy’,’Event 1’);” target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy and pasted the event tracking code directly from your site, then it may need some adjustment with the quotes. You should use the "straight" quotes (and I KNOW there's a name for them.... anyone?). The code should look like this with the fixed single and double quotes:

```
<a href="http://website.com" onClick="ga('send','event','Tickets','Buy','Event 1');" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>
```

The same thing for the ga('create'..) line. Generally make all quotes straight.

Comment: I thought I edited them all, but it looks like I still have to edit some. Let me try. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, they are called smart quotes (the curly ones) and dump quotes (the straight ones). I am unable to see the difference on my computer. However, I can see it here. Thanks so much!